# Nextcloud with Collabora

Tags: nextcloud

We have a nextcloud running with the nextcloud office functions.
Everything works like a charm, except the opening of documents.

We have tried several settings and have googled. So we have had it run through https, direct and through a proxy (both with http and https on the nextcloud server, and serving https from the proxy), we have tried installing collabora as a part of nextcloud. So we are using the built in server.

We get this error when trying to open a file:

```
{
  "message": "Network Error",
  "name": "AxiosError",
  "code": "ERR_NETWORK",
  "config": {
    "transitional": {
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "env": {
      "FormData": null
    },
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "requesttoken": "vQJzhoGtT1zVrIVSFyP0y7MjKH4Qg43frvD5G13XP5M=:iFUl8OjZNiyd1sZnXkTDv8ZFXSdf7t3p7KTPdDiRc7g="
    },
    "method": "get",
    "url": "http://cloud.tectonic-3d.com/extra-apps/richdocumentscode/proxy.php?status"
  },
  "request": {},
  "response": {}
}
```

I have tried to remove and reinstall everything. Also bit by bit. Nothing seems to change the issue. Google keeps returning us to using http or https.

Does anybody have a clue what we need to change to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this problem:

Go to your config file and add these two lines:

```
overwrite.cli.url => https://{your.domain.name}
overwriteprotocol => https
```

Make sure those are the only overwrite options in your config.
Also make sure that if you are behind a reverse proxy, you let nextcloud server the https content, otherwise this won't work.